# Return all of users posts and favourites? Django

Tags: django

I'm creating a summary page of all of the posts the user has liked and all of the posts which the user has created.

I have two models in my db: `Aircraft` & `Airline`. The user can upload posts to either model that they prefer. I'm just slightly clueless on how to retrieve their posts?

**Aircraft Model**

```
class Aircraft(AircraftModelBase):
    manufacturer = SortableForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    aircraft_type = SortableForeignKey(AircraftType)
    body = SortableForeignKey(Body)
    engines = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
```

**Airline Model**

```
class Airline(AirlineModelBase):
    fleet_size = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    alliance = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    average_fleet_age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

In my Accounts app I've made a model of the following:

```
class FavoritedAircraft(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  aircraft = models.ForeignKey(Aircraft)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.aircraft.name


class FavoritedAirline(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  airline = models.ForeignKey(Aircraft)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.airline.name
```

How do I essentially return the users favourite posts and if the user has uploaded anything, those posts as well?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

```
class UploadedAircraft(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  aircraft = models.ForeignKey(Aircraft)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.aircraft.name
```

Answer (score 0):

The favourited category you can query with something like `FavoritedAirline.objects.filter(user=<the_user_here>)`, and it will return an iterable queryset.

However, judging for the implementation of the `Aircraft` and `Airline` models you posted, you have no field referencing who created the post (unless it's defined in your base class). If you add it there as a foreign key, just like you did in the `FavoritedAirline` model, you can use the same sort of query as above.

Comment: How would I implement that?

Comment: Add a line like `creator = models.ForeignKey(User)` to both models. If your db is already created, remember to also create a migration for that. After this, you can query the models filtering by user.

Comment: Okay I've done that. Have a look at the edits. I dont understand how the users uploads will be linked to the UploadedAircraft class? How does django know to assign the uploads there?

Comment: Ok, first, you didn't have to create a new class, you only had to include that one line to the `Airline`and `Aircraft` models. Second, Django doesn't know how to put the data there, this is something that has to be managed in your views. Have you considered doing the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) first?